# Accuracy Calculation

Tags: label, classification, evaluation

I've this code which is supposed to calculate the accuracy of the tagged labels.

```
example_y = [True, False, False, True]
example_pred = [True, True, True, False]
def accuracy(y, pred):
    return sum([1 for y_m, pred_m in zip(y, pred) if y_m == pred_m]) / len(y)
```

The code seems to be working fine but the problem is that I couldn't grasp it... For example why "1", why do we divide by "len(y)", and what exactly is the "_m"? I would be glad for an explanation.

Comment: i recommend you to put your code in this http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit and visualize the execution. no words can explain better than that

Comment: Thanks, that's good idea but it doesn't execute the last line

Comment: Did u call the function?